# Watch not being called on array push

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service for PeerJS that contains an array of active streams. When setting up a WebRTC stream there is a callback that is called when the stream becomes available

```
call.on('stream', function(stream){
    activeStreams.push(URL.createObjectURL(stream));
  });
```

When a stream is available I push it onto the activeStreams array. I then watch this array value in my controller like this:

```
//PeerRTC is the service and .getActiveStreams returns the activeStreams array
$scope.$watch(PeerRTC.getActiveStreams, function(activeStreams) {
  $scope.activeStreams = activeStreams;
}, true);
```

But for some reason the watch callback doesn't execute when I push a url(string) value to the array.

Am I overlooking something? Could it be because the activeStreams value is changing in a callback function?

Comment: If Angular does not know about the change, try wrapping a `$scope.$apply` around your push perhaps.

Comment: I tried doing that but since the value is changed within a service I don't believe I have access to $scope.

Comment: I managed to solve it by attaching an $apply to $rootScope. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some condition, like async call, you will need to call `$scope.apply()` to make it work. Try call it right after you `push` the new data to the array.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the watch variable as an expression string:

```
$scope.$watch('PeerRTC.getActiveStreams', function(activeStreams) {
  $scope.activeStreams = activeStreams;
}, true);
```

[doco](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is "PeerRTC.getActiveStreams"?

By the naming it looks like a function, not an array. (it is a varb).

If it is a function that gets the array, you have to watch the result of invoking the function, not the function itself. as the function stays the same.

```
$scope.$watch('PeerRTC.getActiveStreams()', function(activeStreams) {
  $scope.activeStreams = activeStreams;
}, true);
```

also make sure the array is on the scope.